# Упростить регулярное выражение (время)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Шаблон `12:15:11;` повторяется 4 раза, но в конце отсутствует `;`

```
preg_match('/^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2};\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2};\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2};\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/D', $_POST['time'])
```

Становится непонятно.

Можно записать единожды `\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2};` указать количество повторений 4 и отсутствие `;` в конце ?

Comment: так если проблема только в "не понятно", может вынести шаблон для времени в переменную, и формировать итоговый шаблон [через нее](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d466fcc4055e18dbf5d2917842eecd7afac3c7bc)?

Comment: После последнего времени конец строки или может быть другой текст?

Comment: @ReinRaus, ожидается конец строки, но ввод производит пользователь...

Comment: Если вводит пользователь, то может быть что угодно. Значит нельзя ничего ожидать

Comment: Уточните общую задачу, пожалуйста. Может, не обязательно единственной регуляркой проверять?

Comment: @Sergiks, конечно нет, можно одной регуляркой 4 переменные проверить. Но если бы все ленились изобретать, то мы бы застряли в 19 веке. Ведь в один заход тоже можно проверить.

Comment: Валидность можно проверить и не регуляркой – это может быстрее работать. Например, разбить по `;` в массив и убедиться, что ровно 4 элемента, затем каждый разбить по `:`.

Comment: @Sergiks да ну, бросьте, это несколько строк кода получится если разбивать.

Comment: @Sergiks Я бы сказал, что самым быстрым вариантом был бы конечный автомат пробегающий по строке. Но это в том случае, если бы это делалось на C. А php все таки медленнее будет. А регулярки по крайней мере C-шной функцией сходу обрабатываются (строя тот же КА, только чуть более сложный чем надо). А бить сначала по ; потом по : потом в цикле проверять все элементы на цифры - как минимум несколько проходов по строке

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d(;|$)){4}(?<!;)$
```

Сделано исходя из вашего примера, который говорит, что после 4х времен конец строки.

В данном выражении:

```
(;|$)   - в данном месте может быть ; или конец строки
(?<!;)  - проверяет с забеганием назад, на уже проверенные символы, что в конце не ;
```

Comment: мне кажется пропускает точку с запятой в конце после 4 повторений (PHP 5.5.19)  http://viper-7.com/TN4j8K

Comment: Поправил. Только "упрощением" изначального варианта мне это сложно назвать :)

Comment: @Plush Правда ваш пример на php теперь не пропускает, хотя регулярка верная. Особенности php ... надо подумать

Comment: Может кто улучшит. Честно сказать мне не нравится ни то, что я придумал, ни то, что придумали вы. Но...

Comment: Мне вот такая запись более понятна `preg_match('/^(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d;){3}\d\d:\d\d:\d\d$/', $_POST['time']) ` ей могу доверять, ваш пример хорош, но читать его не берусь, к сожалению

Comment: почему тогде не `(\d\d:){2}\d\d;` :)  ?

Comment: @splash58 А смысл. выглядит менее читабельно, а длина одинаковая

Comment: Майк, вообще-то в вашем примере все как надо, мне не совсем понятно что делает `(;|$)`, я так понимаю, он вместе с отрицающим утверждением `(?<!;)` идет.

Comment: @Plush Он просто говорит что после времени идет `; ИЛИ конец-строки`. А отрицательное незахватывающее утверждение убеждается в том, что в конце все таки не `;`. Только php почему то не понимает, он походу после `$` в первых скобках вообще не смотрит что там позже или как то так. Вот у Qwertiy работающий для php ответ. он делает то же самое, но отсутствие `;` проверяет в самом начале, не захватывающей проверкой с забеганием вперед, и это срабатывает.

Comment: Не понял, про "вообще не смотрит что там позже" - речь идет о том, что не смотрит на `(?<!;)` или ?

Comment: @Plush Ларчик просто открывался. Я для тестов скопировал ваш пример из viper-7.com, который вы в первом коменте дали, а там время 5 раз написано в строке. Разумеется у меня `$` не срабатывал после 4х повторений :) Короче работают все ответы, только к Qwertiy еще $ в конец дописать для надежности

Comment: Другая вариация этого выражения:  `((?<=^|;)\d\d:\d\d:\d\d){4}$` проще этих двух вариаций ничего быть не может. Не ждите решения проще, и так уже проще некуда.

Comment: Ваша вариация почему то не работает, а если бы и работала, то позволяла бы начать строку с `;`

Comment: Точно. `^((?<=^|;)\d\d:\d\d:\d\d){4}$`

Comment: @ReinRaus Все равно не работает. Вы только убеждаетесь в наличии `;` но ее при этом в захват не берете и дальше первого повторения дело не заходит, т.к. \d натыкается на не забранную `;`

Comment: @ReinRaus Ваш вариант должен выглядеть так: `^((?<=^|;)\d\d:\d\d:\d\d;?){4}$`

Comment: Упс. Туплю. `^((^|;)\d\d:\d\d:\d\d){4}$`

Comment: @ReinRaus Неа. `((^|;)\d\d:\d\d:\d\d){4}$` позволяет `;` в начале. и `^` в самом начале это не лечит

Comment: Майк, разница какая-то есть между вашим ответом и Qwertiy ?

Comment: В принципе особо никакой, он проверяет отсутствие `;` в конце заранее, в самом начале выражения, я после выражения.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33572/discussion-on-answer-by-mike----).

Answer (score 4):

> Можно записать единожды \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}; указать количество повторений 4 и отсутствие ; в конце ?

Отсутствие `;` можно и не проверять. Если дописать `;` к проверяемому времени.

```
preg_match('/^(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d;){4}$/D', $_POST['time'].';')
```

Comment: Отличное решение! Проще других == лучше. Тесты проходит.

Comment: За модификатор `D` +1.

Answer (score 3):

```
/^(?!.*;$)(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d(;|$)){4}/
```

Comment: Разъясните, пожалуйста, работу `(?!.*;$)`

Comment: @Plush, это просмотр вперёд с отрицанием. Как `(?=`, но только продолжать если не совпало. Это более базовый синтаксис, чем в принятом ответе, т. е. мой вариант годится не только для php, но и для js.